# How can I find content except folded contents in vim?

Tags: vim

Folding feature with syntax method is pretty well, and it can used to make a kind of "function list". But if I want to find a function name with '/', vim will locate the cursor **on the folded line** to indicate that candidate is in folded contents. Can I avoid this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the fold to open to show the obscured match, you have to restore the default behavior via

```
:set foldopen+=search
```

If you want to jump over (effectively ignoring) matches inside folds, that can be done with a mapping variant of the `n`ext search match command which checks for a closed fold and then re-invokes itself:

```
:nnoremap ,n n:if foldclosed('.') != -1<Bar>execute 'normal ,n'<Bar>endif<CR>
:nnoremap ,N N:if foldclosed('.') != -1<Bar>execute 'normal ,N'<Bar>endif<CR>
```

Comment: Clear,short and effective answer! Its really a pity that vim doesn't build it as an internal feature.